# Accessing last row from table C that has FK from table B, which is in one-to-one relationship with A

Tags: django

Let's say we have 3 models:

```
class A(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)


class B(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class C(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    b = models.ForeingKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and one view:

```
class AListView(generic.ListView):
    model = A
```

In that view (template) I need to show: name of A, name of B and the last row (ordered by date) of "transactioncount" for each repository from b.

In my template I iterate over items in A and show them in following way:

```
{% for a in A %}
<tr>
    <td>{{a.name}}</td>
    <td>{{a.b.name}}</td>
    <td>{{??? Don't know what to put here, to show the last row. I tried: a.b.c|last}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to build custom tags and use template functions like, but that unfortunately doesn't work:

```
{% with a.b.c_set.all|last as val %}
    <td>val</td>
{% endwith}
```

Among my other tries would be to build a new queryset, but then I don't know how to assign items from model A to that queryset. I tried:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'A': A.objects.all(),
        'c_data': C.objects.order_by('B', '-date').distinct(
            'B')
    })
)
```

What would be the best "pythonic" way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of all, don't forget to set the back relation name like:

```
b = models.ForeingKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='all_c')
```

Then:

```
class B(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def last_c(self):
        if self.all_c.exists():
            return self.all_c.order_by('-date').last()
```

In your jinja template just write:

```
a.b.last_c
```

Have fun!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get error: 'B' object has no attribute "c". If I replace following way, it works:

    if self.c.exists(): with if self.all_c.exists(). Is it what you meant?

Comment: Oh yes, it should be: `if self.all_c.exists():`.